# taking only a int from a text with int string in Rust

Tags: string, rust, integer

i need to take only the integer from a string like this "Critical: 3\r\n" , note that the value change everytime so i can't search for "3", i need to search for a generic int.

Thanks.

Comment: You probably want to use regex. Rust has an excellent [regex](https://crates.io/crates/regex) crate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many ways to do it. There are already some answers. Here is one more approach:

```
let s = "Critical: 3\r\n";
let s_res = s.split(":").collect::<Vec<&str>>()[1].trim();
println!("s_res = {s_res:?}");   // "3"
```

In the above code `s_res` will be a string (`&str`). To convert that string to an integer, you can do something like this:

```
let n: isize = s_res.parse().expect("Failed to parse the integer!");    
println!("n = {n}");  // 3
```

Note that, depending on your needs, you might want to add some extra validations/asserts, in case you expect the pattern might change (for example, the number of colons not to be 1, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`chars`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.chars) to get an iterator over the chars of a string, and then apply filter on that iterator to filter out only [digits(`is_digit`)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#method.is_digit).

```
fn main() {
    let my_str: String = "Critical: 3\r\n".to_owned();
    let digits: String = my_str.chars().filter(|char| char.is_digit(10)).collect();
    println!("{}", digits)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on @AlexanderKrauze's comment the most common way to do so is using a regex, which lets you look for any pattern in a String:

```rust
let your_text = "Critical: 3\r\n";
let re = Regex::new(r"\d+").unwrap(); // matches any amount of consecutive digits
let result:Option<Match> = re.find(your_text);// returns the match
let number:u32 = result.map(|m| m.as_str().parse::<u32>().unwrap()).unwrap_or(0); // converts to int
print!("{}", number);
```

would be the code for that. Only one digit is `r"\d"`.

More documentation is found [here](https://docs.rs/regex/latest/regex/index.html).